# Can I change default path.sep in windows?

Tags: node.js

Working on Windows, `path.join` uses separator as `\`.

So, in order to solve this problem, I always have to import `path/posix`

Is there any way to change my default separator to `/`?

Comment: This could be an XY problem. Why are you trying to create a "path-like string that's not a path because it's joined by the wrong character"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have an unavoidable situation that only `/` should be used. Of course I can use another way(kinda tough), but, I just wanted to check my last possibility lol 

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the native `replaceAll()` method.

```js
const path = require("node:path");

var myPath = path.join("path", "to", "whatever");

console.log(
  myPath.replaceAll("\\", "/") // Replace all \ by /
);
```